# Pymodbus : TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, pymodbus

I am trying to use the [modbus_mapper](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/examples/contrib/modbus_mapper.py) in pymodbus and I'm facing the following issue

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lap.py", line 311, in mapping_decoder mapping['addr'] = int(mapping['addr'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

the code is as follows:

```
template = ['addr', 'fun', 'type', 'stat']
def mapping_decoder(mapping_blocks, decoder=None):
for block in mapping_blocks.values():
    for mapping in block.values():
        print(mapping)
        print(block.values())
        mapping['addr'] = int(mapping['addr'])
```

Printing the print(mapping) & print(block.values()) i am receiving the following output :

40001
dict_values(['40001', 'int', 'Pac'])

please help me in solving this issue

Comment: The error and printed values are clear: `mapping` is the string `'40001'`. Did you mean `block['addr'] = int(block['addr'])`?

Comment: I'm trying to update the mapper.py file to the latest python version. Your suggestion worked and the error is not appearing now. Thank you.